# Regexp: match anything except digits, spaces, comma, semicolon, 'am', and 'pm'

Tags: regex

I'm trying to check if the incoming string contains any symbols not related to defining time period, so I'm trying to find a regexp that would match anything except digits, spaces, comma, semicolon, 'am', and 'pm'.

Here's what I've come to but this still matches am and pm: `/([^,:-\d\s])+/`

How do I add `am` and `pm` to exceptions?

Googling unfortunately did not help. Here's link to regexr with above expression and a text to test: https://regexr.com/5ber7

Comment: Valid time:  `475:93;;;ampm`? Why not simply match a valid time positively?

Comment: Try `(?:(?![ap]m)[^,:\d\s-])+(?<![ap]m)`, but it is too awkward. What is the language? JavaScript? What is the expected output for a `'matching text' : , - am pm 'matching text'` string?

Comment: @PatrickArtner because the incoming string may be more than one time period and this is only first of validations

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, your regexp works just like it should. Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:(?![ap]m)[^,:\d\s-])+(?<![ap]m)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regexr.com/5besh)

It works because the excluded string is just two chars long. **Details**:

- `(?:(?![ap]m)[^,:\d\s-])+` - one or more chars other than digits, `,`, `:`, whitespace and `-` that do not start an `am` or `pm` char sequences
- `(?<![ap]m)` - no `am` or `pm` allowed immediately before the current location.